# Randomly play audio variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Before I enter the view, I want the controller to randomly choose an audio file and play it. I honestly have no idea where to even start.

Controller:

```
var audioone = new Audio("img/1.mp3");
var audiotwo = new Audio("img/2.mp3");
var audiothree = new Audio("img/3.mp3");

$scope.$on("$ionicView.beforeEnter", function () {
//something to do with Math.Rand() and then I have no clue?

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. FYI The idea is when the user gets to that view, he will hear random words of encouragement and I need them to be random because I do not want to user to get bored of hearing the same audio in the same order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I would do it. I put an array for audio sources, randomize by using Math functions, then return it back.

```js
var audios = ['img/1.mp3', 'img/2.mp3', 'img/3.mp3'];

var generateRandomAudio = function(audios) {
  var audio = new Audio(audios[Math.floor(Math.random() * audios.length)]);
  return audio;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="generateRandomAudio(audios)">Generate</button>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! I never would've come up with that formula...really clever

Answer (score 0):

```
var audios = ['img/1.mp3', 'img/2.mp3', 'img/3.mp3'];
$scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function () {
  var audio = new Audio(audios[Math.floor(Math.random() * audios.length)]);
  return audio;
});
```

But you must integreate a plugin cordova like [NativeAudio](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/nativeAudio/) or [Media](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/media/).

Look at this example: [Playing Audio In Your Android And iOS Ionic Framework App](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/11/playing-audio-android-ios-ionicframework-app/). I hope to help you.

Good luck!

Comment: Please add some commentary to your answer to help the OP understand how it works. Also, you should probably provide further guidance on what to do with the return value